# I submitted a bbsrc fellowship proposal. Does my institute own this material?

Tags: funding, research-proposal, intellectual-property, academic-freedom

I have applied for a bbsrc fellowship. It was not funded. Now I am leaving this institute. In my contract it is written that all electronic material produced during the working time belongs to them

My question is whether also my fellowship proposal belongs to them and I need to leave copies of the content on their servers. Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear. First, you said "_It was not funded._", then you asked "_whether also my fellowship belongs to them_". Did you get the fellowship?

Comment: No. I mean does my institute needs to have a copy of the proposal?

Comment: I edited your question to include the word "proposal".

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what the word bbsrc means ... or is it an acronym (uppercase?) for something, and if so, what? Don't assume that most readers of academia will know the argot of your particular domain.

Answer (score 2):

[IANAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL) so I can't definitively answer this from a legal point of view.  But I can say that irrespective of whether the institute could legally demand a copy of the fellowship,  they won't do and no one will expect you to leave a copy. Indeed I can almost guarantee that any files you leave in any personal area of the institutional file server will be deleted shortly after you leave (unless special arrangements have been made). If you submitted the fellowship to the BBSRC, this will have been done through Je-S,  and they will have a copy through that process anyway,  if they really cared,  which I'm almost certain they don't.